# trouble getting started with requests testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

Go gentle on me: I've got the flu and only a few of my neural synapses are firing!

Here's a simple requests test for RSpec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Home Page' do
  it 'should mention Home' do
    get '/'
    response.body.should have_content("Home")
  end

end
```

Great.  It works.  Now I want to verify that there's an image loaded when visting the home page as well.  I assume there's a matcher for images similar to have_content(), so I first go looking for the definition of have_content().

Not found in

```
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/search?query=have_content
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/
```

But the I remember that RSpec has nifty naming rules for matchers, so (e.g.) `even?() => be_even()`.  But even then, searching for "content" in the above doesn't find anything.

*(As an aside, I'm pretty sure I'm not looking for the Capybara method of the same name, since I'm doing a `get` and not `visit`.  Right?)*

At the risk of getting this question rejected for being too vague: where the heck is this method coming from, and where do I learn what else I can pass to `response.body.should`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec request specs use Capybara, so you can use either `get` or `visit`.

If you want to just check that the page has an `<img>` element with the correct link, you could use:

```
response.should have_selector('img', :src => '...')
```

Comment: So just to make sure I understand: even though I did a Rails `get` (and not a Capybara `visit`), I can still use Capybara's `have_content()` matcher on the resulting response.body?  (And `have_selector()` on the resulting response?)

Comment: Sorry what I wrote was a bit misleading. You can use both `get` and `visit` but they are different. Check out this blog post: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/06/improving-the-integration-between-capybara-and-rspec/ But you definitely can use `have_selector` on the response from `get`.

Comment: Good enough for the checkmark.  I've found the docs on the Capybara RSpec matchers, but not much info on how to use them.  For example, when do you use `response.body.should <matcher>` vs `response.should <matcher>`?

Comment: You're not the first to remark on the lack of documentation for capybara matchers. I've also found it a bit disappointing, given how powerful capybara is.